# How to remove repeated number from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

How to completely remove repeated numbers from an array?

For example, if:

```js
const array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5]
```

The output should be:

```
[3, 5]
```

Comment: If it is a sorted array it can be done in O(1) space complexity . Else you have to take a set to check for elements

Answer (score 1):

Use an Object where the key is the number, and the value is the number of occurrences. Than reduce it back to the desired array of values:

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,3,1,2,5];

const res = Object.entries(arr.reduce((ob, v) => {
  if (!(v in ob)) ob[v] = 0;
  ob[v] += 1;                       // Count occurrences
  return ob;
}, {})).reduce((arr, [k, v]) => {   // Reduce back to Array
  if (v === 1) arr.push(+k);        // Only keys with 1 occurrence
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(res);                   // [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for keeping track of seen items, by taking an array with the value or set the arrays value to zero.

Finally flat the result set to remove empty arrays.

```js
const
    array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5],
    result = array
        .reduce((o => (r, v) => {
            if (v in o) o[v].length = 0;
            else r.push(o[v] = [v]);            
            return r;
        })({}), [])
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a clever approach, it doesn't need to do counting explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Roko and Ke1vans had answered in functional approaches. Both of them are correct. However, I'd show an answer in imperative approach, which may seems easier for new comer.

Similar to their flow. First, we count the occurrence of each number. Then we select the numbers that has occurred once (hence being non-repeated) into the output array.

```js
let array = [1,1,2,3,1,2,5]
let counts = {}
let output = []

// loop each elements in the array as `item`
for(let item of array) {
  // If the item is not set in the counts, `counts[item]` will be `undefined`.
  // Using `|| 0` means use zero as fallback value if the items is unseen.
  let count = counts[item] || 0
  counts[item] = count + 1
}

// loop each keys in the object (key-value pairs) as `item`
for(let item in counts) {
  let count = counts[item]
  if(count == 1) {
    // `+item` converts the key from string into number
    output.push(+item)
  }
}

console.log(output) // will print out `[ 3, 5 ]`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and create a map of values. later iterate and filter.

```js
const data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5];

const findUniques = (data = []) => {
  const map = data.reduce((m, num) => {
    m[num] = (m[num] || 0) + 1;
    return m;
  }, {});
  return data.filter((num) => map[num] === 1);
};

console.log(findUniques(data));
```

You can also do the same using 2 set, or 2 array.

```js
const data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5];
const findUniques2 = (data = []) => {
  let unique = new Set();
  let seen = new Set();
  for (let num of data) {
    if (seen.has(num)) unique.delete(num);
    else unique.add(num);
    seen.add(num);
  }
  return Array.from(unique);
};
console.log(findUniques2(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Array.filter()** [*(Array filter article)*](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/) for this 
 for Example :

```js
const a = [ 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 4 , 5 , 7];

function filter(value , index , array){

    // looping through all the objects in the array
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(i != index && array[i] == value) return false; // return 'false' if the value has a duplicate other than itself
    }
    // return 'TRUE' if value hasn't been duplicated
    return true;

}

const b = a.filter(filter); // [3, 4, 5, 7]
```

And the short version if this function's going to be used only once:

```js
const a = [ 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 4 , 5 , 7];

const b = a.filter((value , index , array) => {
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) if(i != index && array[i] == value) return false;
    return true;
}); 

// [3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find duplicates and then operate a difference.

```
let a = [1,1,2,3,1,2,5];
const findDuplicates = (nums) => {
    nums.sort(); // alters original array
    let ans = []
  
    for(let i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
      if(nums[i] === nums[i+1]){
         if(ans[ans.length -1] !== nums[i]){
            ans.push(nums[i])
         }
      } 
    }
    return ans;
  }
duplicates = new Set(findDuplicates(a))
let difference = new Set([...a].filter(x => !duplicates.has(x)))
console.log(Array.from(difference))
```

output : [ 3, 5 ]

Note : I grab the findDuplicates function from this [link](https://dev.to/huyddo/find-duplicate-or-repeat-elements-in-js-array-3cl3)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5];

const s = new Set();

const res = data.filter((a, i) => {
    if (data.lastIndexOf(a) > i || s.has(a)) {
        s.add(a);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

console.log(res); //=> [3, 5]
```